Trying to split a string using Regular expression where first and Last word has to be removed
I have a string as below:-
string= "None I am using a new technology test"

I have used split [string.split(" ")] but cannot write a reg ex where my output should be
Str_output= "I am using a new technology"

Basically the First and Last word of the string has to be excluded.
string.split(" ")[1]+string.split(" ")[2]+string.split(" ")[3] and so on

Did you attempt to write any regex? Please include your attempts in the question.

This does not need a regex if you can use split.

Why not just split(" ") and then leave off the 2 end array elements when forwarding your result? Either through an array copy or simply not adding them to some container / iterating those indices. A lot less cognitive overhead than a regex with lookarounds or grouping behaviors.

must it be split()? must it be regular expression?

Or something like String[] tokens = string.split(" +");String toppedAndTailed = IntStream.range(1, tokens.length-1).mapToObj(i ->tokens[i]).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

( weird but split: ....split(" ",2)[1].split(" [^ ]+$")[0] )  No regular expression: str.substring(str.indexOf(" ")+1, str.lastIndexOf(" "))

This piece of code should work
String s= "None I am using a new technology test";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\w+\\s(.*)\\s\\w+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));

^\\w+\\s matches the first word including the fist space
\\s\\w+$ matches the last word including the last space
.* machtes the rest
And the output is:

I am using a new technology



If topic starter doesn't trim input string, the result will be empy
If there is more spaces between words than one, then result will contain empty characters from sides.
If string contains 2 words and 3 or more spaces between them, then the result will be sequence of spaces.
Edited regexp ^\s*\w+\s+(.+\b)\s+\w+\s*$


@Yunnosch why do you think this question is spam?

Then don’t put it on an unrelated answer, put the comment on the related question, so we I have the context

You can more easily (IMHO) skip

.split() which requires taking apart and putting back together the string
regex which is way more complicated and error prone

and just use .indexOf() (searches from the start) and .lastIndexOf() (searches from the end). Then slice the string using .substring(first, last) to remove the first and last word.
Steps:

find the first space using s.indexOf(" ") (need to add one to start on the character after the space)
find the last space using s.lastIndexOf(" ")
slice the string using s.substring(first, last)

Code with each step broken out
String s = "None I am using a new technology test";
int first = s.indexOf(" ") + 1;
System.out.println(first);
int last = s.lastIndexOf(" ");
System.out.println(last);
System.out.println(s.substring(first, last));

or more compact
String s = "None I am using a new technology test";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1, s.lastIndexOf(" ")));


@DavidConrad Updated. Let me know if you have more feedback.

With Java streams, you do not even need a regex:
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String text = "None I am using a new technology test";
        List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));
        System.out.println(lst.stream().skip(1).limit(lst.size()-2).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
    }
}
// => I am using a new technology

See the online Java demo.

.skip(1) - omits the first item ("word")
.limit(lst.size()-2) - limits the size to the lst size minus 2 (to remove the last "word")
.collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) - joins the string back.


This regular expression returns substring without first and last word, it takes in account spaces at the beggining and at the end of an input string.
(?<=\b ).+\b(?!\s*$|\S)
There is only single drawback. If input string has more then one space between frist and second word, the result substring will include extra spaces at the beggining of itself
